# Read multiple arduino's using a Raspberry Pi 3 through USB

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have 3 arduino's that have RC522 rfid readers attached to them. They each have their own power supplies and they are connected to a raspberry pi 3 via the usb ports. I am getting really inconsistent results when running the reader in python. It does appear all 3 are reading but the loop does some weird things. Sometimes the chip code keeps repeating after the chip is removed and other times it works properly. There does not appear to be any consistency with which arduino is behaving oddly either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is the arduino code (The same code was copied to each arduino with the exception of the initial println that indicates which arduino is connected).

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         5          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          53         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define MOSI_PIN        51
#define MISO_PIN        50
#define SCK_PIN         52

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Instance of the class

MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

String read_rfid;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522

  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }

  Serial.println(F("The Toy Maker's Sanctuary RDIF Reader 1 Online."));
  //Serial.println(F("Using the following key:"));
  //printHex(key.keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
}

void loop() {

  // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
  if ( ! rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
      return;

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
      return;

    dump_byte_array(rfid.uid.uidByte, rfid.uid.size);
    Serial.println(read_rfid);
}

/*
   Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
*/
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
  read_rfid = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    read_rfid = read_rfid + String(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
```

Here is the python code

```
import serial

ser0=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=1)
ser1=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM1", 9600, timeout=1)
ser2=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM2", 9600, timeout=1)

ser0.baudrate=9600
ser1.baudrate=9600
ser2.baudrate=9600

read_ser0=""
read_ser1=""
read_ser2=""

while True:
    read_ser0=ser0.readline()
    print("0: ",read_ser0)
    read_ser1=ser1.readline()
    print("1: ",read_ser1)
    read_ser2=ser2.readline()
    print("2: ",read_ser2)

    read_ser0=""
    read_ser1=""
    read_ser2=""
```

Comment: Does it work reliably with just one Arduino connected? With two? Does it work reliably if you wait say 50ms if no new card is present?

Comment: Try putting in a delay of a few microseconds and see if that fixes it. I find serial comms sometimes need a microdelay like that to work properly.

Comment: It works perfectly with one connected. Where should I add the delay? There's a timeout in the Serial declaration in python. Should it be in the loop in python or in the arduino code?